# hundreds of persons VS. hundreds persons

Tags: vocabulary, grammatical-number

**hundreds of persons**

**hundreds persons**

Could you please learn me what is the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Hundreds persons"?! Where have you seen this? I can't seem to make a crystal clear usage of it.

Comment: 'Persons' makes you sound like a lawyer. Use 'people'… most people would ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use hundreds then it is followed by of. "hundreds persons/people" is wrong.
Structures of the type "how much/ how many of what" use "of" in English with few exceptions and fall under the heading partitive or partitive genitive.

Why do we say "hundreds of demonstrators but a hundred/one hundred demonstrators 
(without of)?

Answer:You say fifty persons because it is a numeral. Though a hundred/one hundred still has some features of a noun it is regarded as a numeral, whereas hundreds is regarded as a noun describing a quantity just as a lot of/ a quantity of etc.

Comment: If answers to "how many?" use "of", why don't we say "one hundred of people"?

Comment: You say fifty persons because it is a numeral. Though a hundred/one hundred still has some features of a noun it is regarded as a numeral, whereas hundreds is regarded as a noun describing a quantity just as a lot of/ a quantity of etc.

Comment: That would be a helpful clarification to add to your answer.

Comment: A lot of work but I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to be reading from the [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/of)? It says:

> **of** *preposition* (AMOUNT)
>
> used after words or phrases expressing amount, number, or a particular unit:
>
> - a kilo of apples
>   loads of food
>   hundreds of people
>   most of them
>   both of us
>   a third of all people
>   a speck of dust
>   a drop of rain

In any case, the word *of* cannot be removed from **any of those** phrases; the resulting phrase would sound unidiomatic and ungrammatical.

Comment: It's not in the question as written, but OP might be confused because we don't say "one hundred of people".

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to believe that the first one is true. We have the structure: amount + of + N. Any other statemtent with no "of" is wrong. I also found a passage which contains an equivalent example to the usage of the phrase "hundreds of persons"
http://dethi.violet.vn/present/show/entry_id/239291